# Validate configuration changes via salt

Tags: saltstack

Background: recently I discovered an issue on our servers where zookeeper wouldn't start on one of them.  It was caused by the myid file being empty (it requires a number).  Executing salt didn't fix it.  It turns out that the issue was cause by a recent hostname change.  I fixed the sls file, but any such tweak may cause it to break again.

So, my question is: can I use salt to validate that certain changes were correctly applied?  In this case, I could check the size of the file or validate that the contents contained a single number.  Ideally this would be run as part of the execution of a state, but if there's another way I'd love to hear it.

Just to be specific, I'm not looking to validate or lint the state file themselves.  I just want to ensure that the end results are valid to some degree.  E.g. the file contains a single number and isn't empty.

Comment: Have a look at serverspec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go along with [Roald Nefs' answer](https://serverfault.com/a/832099/376314), you can use `module.run` within a state to execute a module within a state.  So, for my case, I ended up doing this:

```
myid_file_test:
    module.run:
        name: file.search
        path: /path/to/myid
        pattern: '\d'
```

If the pattern fails to match, then it will report a failure, which is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

With the [salt.module.file](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html) module you would be able to  manage information about regular files, directories, and special files on the minion, set/read user, group, mode, and data.

This modules includes a [`search()`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html#salt.modules.file.search) function which allows you to search for occurrences of a pattern in a file.

```
salt '*' file.search /path/to/the/file pattern='='
```

The pattern is a regular expression, to be matched using Python's [`search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search).

You could use the [`diskusage()`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html#salt.modules.file.diskusage) function to recursively calculate disk usage of path and return it in bytes:

```
salt '*' file.diskusage /path/to/the/file
```